# Bootstrap 3: Span elements floating right in list-group-item do not consume vertical space

Tags: css, html, css-float, twitter-bootstrap-3

In a Bootstrap 3 `list-group-item`, I have an icon, some text, and two icons / buttons that should float right.

I tried this:

```
<a class="list-group-item" ng-click="handleClick()">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
    Some text goes here
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning pull-right" ng-click="handleButtonClick()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
    <some:custom:span></some:custom:span> 
</a>
```

This works great if the result fits in one line:

[image: rendering with wide window]

It also works when the window is so thin that the actual text does not fit in one line:

[image: the text wrapped, leaving a place for the pull-right spans]

However, if the windows allows the text to stay in one line, but there is not enough space for the pull-right spans, things get messed up:

[image: float sticks out below]

What I'd actually want is that the `pull-right` spans start a new line and align right, and the `list-group-item` extends vertically for them to fit. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

To keep the buttons aligned wrap a new element around them and float the wrapping element. Then clear the `float` on list items with the `.clearfix` class to fix their height.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    <span class="pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
      <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/EpG7x/.

However, placing buttons within a link is not valid according to the [HTML5 specification from W3C](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).

> The [`a`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables,
>   and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive
>   content within (e.g. buttons or other links).

A similar result can be achieved using panels with tables instead.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </td>
        <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

To prevent content inside a cell from wrapping, you can use the `.text-nowrap` class (added in Bootstrap v3.2.0).

See live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/cdog/6mFDH/.

Comment: Thank you! I went with the first version, but replaced my `a` with a `span`, which should make it legal, and manually added the `:hover` effect (which Bootstrap applies to `span.list-group-item:hover` only by default). It works exactly as expected.
Do you know any good document I should have read to find the `clearfix`-way myself?

Comment: Floated elements do not add to the height of the element they reside in properly. A similar scenario is described here: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
Text Here
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Delete('')"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
</li>
```

This will work for bootstrap 4.0 latest v