# Bootstrap 3: make panel's text wrap under icons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

looking an older question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868664/bootstrap-3-span-elements-floating-right-in-list-group-item-do-not-consume-vert) I would like the text to wrap **underneath** the right aligned icons when the panel is squeezed.

Here is the code I find well done so far:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea even using other classes than `panel` of bootstrap 3 will also be considered.
Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/centurianii/4j6fpfk2/) or

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </td>
          <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
            <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The use of a table is to have them in their own column, you would need to use divs.

Answer (score 1):

If you lost the table and went to divs you could use bootstraps responsive grid system and push/pull the columns as needed. To make the text align right when collapsed you could repeat the text and hide/show based on the screen: https://jsfiddle.net/4j6fpfk2/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-push-10 text-right">
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-info">CCS</button>
          <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
          </button>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-pull-2 col-xs-12">
          <div class="visible-xs text-right">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </div>
          <div class="hidden-xs text-left">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          </div>
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could also create a class that changes the align properties based on media queries if you didn't want to repeat the text

Comment: Too much cluttered code. Don't want to repeat text. It's a kind of micro-snippet. I would like to avoid grids. If I use absolute positioning of 2 buttons at the upper right corner and force text to wrap under it when space is narrow?

Comment: Your idea of pushing & pulling gave me some inspiration: what about this minimal solution with pulled button group? (https://jsfiddle.net/4j6fpfk2/2/)

Comment: OK, that works. I misunderstood your question thinking you wanted the div to push down when collapsed. Glad you got it working!